# My HDD seems to lose some files from time to time

Tags: hard-drive

I noticed this while downloading a game. I could unpack the zip file but with a few errors on some files.

I decided to download the same zip again on a different folder. Now the unpacking again gave out some errors. But not on the same files.

I managed to copy the 2 unzipped filed into 1 working, but this sometimes requires for me to download 10-12 copies of the same game and combine them together like a puzzle until I have all the files that are unpacked correctly.

Also another aspect is that sometimes a program I use just gives me an error that a file is missing, then do a check and it finds the missing file and have to redownload the whole thing.  I have not deleted anything.

I have tried formatting the whole thing.  I don't know what is the problem.

**UPDATE:** Just ran a speed test on Speedtest.net by Ookla 65.06 Mbps download and 43.45 Mbps upload speed. Never had problems with my network con either the ISP. My system is not a new one; system is roughly 5-6 years old:

- **CPU:** AMD Athlon X2 Dual Core Processor.
- **Motherboard:** Asus M2N SE Plus Motherboard.
- **RAM:** 2GB DDR2 RAM
- **Storage:** WD 1TB hard drive with an additional 120 SSD drive; which I find out I cant use on full capacity because I dont have SATA # conection on my motherboard.

Comment: Just ran a speed test on OOKLA 65.06 Mbps download and 43.45 Mbps upload speed.never had problems with my network con either the ISP.my system is not a new one i have a AMD Athlon X2 Dual core processor , Asus M2N se plus motherboard , 2gb of ddr2 memory and a WD 1Tb hard drive with an aditiona 120 SSD... wich i find out i cant use on full capacity because i dont have SATA # conection on my motherboard.sysetm is roughly 5-6 years... but HDD is newer than that. not sure when i brought it tho. couldnt be more than 4 years tho.

Comment: If you don't use your DVD drive, you should be able to unplug it and plug the SSD in its place.  That 120 gig drive is extremely valuable in terms of performance.

Comment: The problem you have is really troublesome. Could you please specify if the problem appears only with the data stored on the HDD or on both the drives you are using? Have you tried downloading and saving a file with a live Linux CD? Are you overclocking any of the components? Do you remember making any changes to the system before the problem started manifesting? I would also suggest you test your RAM to begin with.

Comment: The problem appeard only on the HDD , i have not tryed downloading a linux live cd.no overclocking , no changes where made to the system for 4 years aprox. when i brought the HDD. I would like to test my RAM ... only thing is dont know how. i will specify now.. im a noob when it comes to anything higher than installing windows.

Comment: also i had finnaly some free time so i installed a new copy of win on my SSD ... so the bugged HDD its now only working as a storage. but my problem still remains. i cant save all the data from it... cuz some files are not complete or missing.. or just cant be copied( i dont really know the reason why)

Answer (score -1):

This sounds to me like a serious problem, and definately not something that should be happening.  That said, It is premature to blame the hard drive - although it could be responsible.It could also be a software error (antivirus or malware ?), or, conceivably, a CPU issue.

You can rule out the possibility of it being the hard drive by
(1) Checking the S.M.A.R.T status of the drive - if it comes out OK, doing a disk cehck on the drive - for example by using a Linux boot CD and the badblocks command.

Have you worked out if the problem only occurs on Internet downloads, and have you tried downloading and checking files against their published checksums ?  Doing this could help confirm or rule out an error with your Internet connection causing corruption "in-flight"

Comment: The SMART test came out ok. as to the rest of your suggestions i cannot test them because i really dont know what that stuff is. never used linux.an no ideea how to check files against their published checksums. will try to look ito it. but the linux part i think is way beyond my knowledge.but i thank you for your help anyway :D